# trying pulling contacts related to an account for Opportunities that are open and meet a specific field

Tags: soql

I'm trying the following:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact 
WHERE AccountId IN 
    (SELECT AccountId 
            FROM Opportunity 
            WHERE Manufacturer_Name__c= 'Universal Containers')
```

I'm trying to pull for a different value than Universal Containers (this is a placeholder). However I'm received an error stating that the ID field Value for Universal Containers is invalid. I've double checked my spelling etc.

Where am I going wrong.

Comment: What is the data type of `Manufacturer_Name__c`, I am assuming that it must be a look up field.

Answer (score 0):

In your example above and based on the run time error, `Manufacturer_Name__c` appears to be a lookup or a form of ID reference to another database table. Using `__r.Name` you can traverse through the relationship and reference the record Name instead.

Example provided, if `Manufacturer_Name__c` is truly the SObject API name.

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact 
WHERE AccountId IN 
    (SELECT AccountId 
            FROM Opportunity 
            WHERE Manufacturer_Name__r.Name = 'Universal Containers')
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message that you are getting, it seems that `Manufacturer_Name__c` field is either a lookup or master detail field.

And such type of fields i.e. relationship fields stores the 18 digit ID of the parent record i.e. it does not store the `Name` field although it displays the `Name` on the detail page layout.

For such cases, you should compare it with `Name` field instead

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact 
WHERE AccountId IN 
    (SELECT AccountId 
            FROM Opportunity 
            WHERE Manufacturer_Name__r.Name= 'Universal Containers')
```